# Consequences after fixing an error when creating a page in Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, ssl, https, error-handling

I've been recommended this website to get help for this issue, hopefully I can post this here. I've been getting the error “The response is not a valid JSON response” whenever I try to create a page or edit a page. I installed Really Simple SSL plugin and activated it, I had an SSL certification so it should have been alright. It didn't really fix it for me, but I tried changing the permalinks from post titles to plain and it seemed to work, but I was wondering what would happen if I switched back to post titles. What I did next was, I deactivated the SSL plugin and activated it again, and then I switched back to post titles. I could now edit all my pages. But I am wondering if these kinds of changes made changes to the site and if this could cause problems further along the line and also if this could be a permanent fix to the problem?

Thanks,
Gustavs

Comment: This is a fairly common issue with the Gutenberg editor and can happen for a number of reasons. It sounds like your configuration is back the way to want it and you are no longer getting errors, is that correct?

Comment: Looks like an issue with Guttenberg editor, try updating PHP to  7.2.3 
 . Atemporary solution is to active classic editor.

Comment: I don't think I am using anything called Gutenberg editor, I don't really know what that means, if it is the default wordpress editor then yes I am using it. I will try updating PHP and give feedback. Also I am not getting errors anymore that is right.